# CFFILE get file issue

Tags: oracle, coldfusion

I managed to get the FTP connection to a remote server (an oracle server) using ColdFusion2016 CFFILE.

I need to get OracleData.txt file from the oracle server at this directory: /oracle/admin/mydbname/myfolder/OracleData.txt but I keep getting error message saying:

An error occurred during the sFTP putFile operation.
Error: /home/www/TestFolder/XX/MyTestFile.txt (No such file or directory).

This directory (/home/www/TestFolder/XX/) is valid and it is there, this is a unix server dir. I can acces this dir through FileZilla just fine.

So my codes look like this:

```
  <!--- open connection ---><!--- This works! --->
  <!--- cfftp.succeeded: Returns YES --->
  <cfftp action="open"
         connection="myConn"
     username="validusername"
     password="validpassword"
     port="22"
     server="mycompany.com"
     stopOnError="true"
     fingerprint="valid:finger:print:value"
     secure="YES"
     timeout="300">            

  <!--- This doesn't work ---><!--- it returns no such file or directory error --->
  <cfftp connection = "myConn"
         action = "putFile"
         name = "uploadFile"
         transferMode = "binary"
         localFile = "/home/www/TestFolder/XX/MyTestFile.txt"
         remoteFile =  "OracleData.txt">
```

I'm confuse with the attribute localFile and remoteFile.
Is my understanding correct when I put the OracleData.txt, the file I want to get from oracle directory, here? 
What is localFile attribute for??? I thought I have to assign a directory to where OracleData.txt should be copied into. There is no file in this unix directory

Comment: According to https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-f/cfftp-connection-file-and-directory-operations.html it seems that localFile refers to a file in memory.

Comment: Talk to your server admin people.  Ask them where the ftp root is on that server.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  You say you need to `get` a file from the server but are having difficulty with `put` operations.

Comment: I tried both put and get interchangeably when testing but the last attempt was using GetFile, not so sure what the difference between the two. As I'm writing this comment I just read Adobe doc. It says I need to Enable ColdFusion Security option on the Sandbox Security page and I just did. Then I ran my codes again & I got MyTestFile.txt created in my unix dir but it is a blank txt instead of OracleData.txt.

Answer (score 0):

- If your ColdFusion server is running on "Server A", and you want to move the file from "Server B" back to "Server A", then use `action="GetFile"`.
- If you want to take the file from "Server A" and move it to Server B, then use `action="PutFile"`

Other recommendations I would make is that you should get rid of the first `open` connection block and just use the `get` or `put` command directly with server password and username in it.  I have found that the reuse of a connection is actually rather buggy, and you get better/more reliable performance results by just transferring the file directly.

What I would further suggest is that you do a little experiment with the `listDir` action to make sure that you are in the root directory that you want to be in.  That is, you can do:

```
<cfftp action="ListDir"
   directory="/home" name="local.qList" 
   username="validusername"
   password="validpassword"
   port="22"
   server="mycompany.com"
   stopOnError="true"
   fingerprint="valid:finger:print:value"
   secure="YES"
   timeout="300">  

<cfdump var="#local.qList#">
```

If you do that, then you'll get some idea of what the directory is that you are specifying.  You can play around with that and change the directory value to dial in what the directory value should be.